# iOS UITableView : Most efficient way to handle multiple cells that can be deleted, updated or created?

Tags: ios, uitableview

Right now,  I am getting data from an API and populating my `UITableView` with the data. Problem is the data can be updated, removed or there can be new data. Currently, I just repopulate the data source array again with the data and call `reloadData. This actually works well, but I feel like there can be a more effecient way of doing this. Any tips or suggestions are appreciated.

It seems hard to keep up with what data has been updated, created or removed.

Edit : Here is an example what the data looks like. Remember this data can be deleted, updated with new text or new data can show up.

```
"content": [
        {
            "id": "0",
            "text": "zero"
        },
        {
            "id": "1",
            "text": "one"
        },
```

Edit 2: Sorry, but I forgot to add, I store the data from API in a database first. Then, I populate the `UITableView` from the data stored in database. Still, even with this it seems hard and might just be easier to repopulate my array and reload the tableview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no concrete way of doing this. But a few things can be done to improve performance.

- Take reactive approach. When your data changes, your tableview should react or update itself where necessary.
- Don't reload all the cells in the tableview. Only reload those cell where data has been changed. Maybe reload sections where it's necessary.